# Specify bolt port for a neo4j docker container

Tags: c#, docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I have two neo4j containers created using a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4jdev1:
    image: neo4j
    ports: 
         - "7474:7474"
         - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
         - $HOME/neo4jdev1/data:/data
    expose:
         - "7687"
         - "7474"
  neo4jdev2:
    image: neo4j
    ports: 
         - "7475:7474"
         - "7689:7689"
    volumes:
         - $HOME/neo4jdev2/data:/data
    expose:
         - "7689"
         - "7475"
```

When I run this using `docker-compose up`, I get the two services running. I checked those by visiting the following URLS.

`https://192.168.99.100:7474`

`https://192.168.99.100:7475`

As you can see I am trying to expose port 7689 for my second service because I want to use it as the port for bolt instead of the default 7687.

In my unit tests, I tried to connect to bolt using both drivers.

## Test 1 (using port 7687) - PASS

`IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://192.168.99.100:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "password"));`

## Test 2 (using port 7689) - FAIL

`IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://192.168.99.100:7689", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "password"));`

Here's what I have done so far. I edited the config file inside the container located at `/var/lib/neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf`. I changed this line from

`dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687` to `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7689`

After saving the config file, the test still fails and the bolt port still shows 7687 in the neo4j browser.

[image]

Is there another way to specify the bolt port on the docker-compose file or is there another way to change the bolt port in the running container itself?

Comment: What is the error message in the failed test? Could be a problem with the SSL connection if both DBs run on the same host. Then there will be an error on the second connection because the certificate does not match what is stored in `~/.neo4j/known_hosts`

Comment: @MartinPreusse the exceotion is `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.99.100:7689`. By the way, I'm using Neo4j Driver for C#

Comment: Just added the answer i found below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
neo4jdev2:
  image: neo4j
  ports: 
     - "7475:7474"
     - "7689:7687"
  volumes:
     - $HOME/neo4jdev2/data:/data
```

For the ports part, the first port is the one used outside the container, the second one is used inside the container.

Comment: Also if you put a port under _ports_, you don't need to put it under _expose_ too. It is done automatically by Docker.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run several neo4j docker containers in parallel on one server you get in trouble with the bolt port. So you must specify a different internal bolt port for each container with the **NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address**

**Example docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4jmedcon:
    image: neo4j
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "none"
      NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "localhost:10031"
    ports:
     - "10030:7474"
     - "10031:7687"
    volumes:
     - $HOME/docker/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf
     - $HOME/docker/neo4j/medcon/data:/var/lib/neo4j/data
     - $HOME/docker
  neo4jMK-Constance:
    image: neo4j
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "none"
      NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "localhost:10081"
    ports:
     - "10080:7474"
     - "10081:7687"
    volumes:
     - $HOME/docker/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf
     - $HOME/docker/neo4j/MK-Constance/data:/var/lib/neo4j/data
     - $HOME/docker
```